# Using Javascript I want to import an XML from url and then convert it to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, xml

Using Javascript... I am trying to figure out how to import the xml from here:

http://gamebattles.majorleaguegaming.com/xboxone/call-of-duty-black-ops-iii/team/team-cnk/stats.xml

and then convert it into Json so I can use it with AngularJS and display it on a front end app.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to show us what you've already got for us to help fix it :)

Comment: I love stealing ideas from "online this and that" :)
http://www.utilities-online.info/assets/js/ObjTree.js

Comment: well I don't have much right now. I've tried a couple examples I've found.. most recently:    

var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
            x.open("GET", "http://gamebattles.majorleaguegaming.com/xboxone/call-of-duty-black-ops-iii/team/team-cnk/stats.xml", true);
            x.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200) {
                    var doc = x.responseXML;
                    console.log(doc);
                }
            };
            x.send(null)
but I get: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to convert the XML to JSON.  Are you sending it to another server?  Why not just operate on the XML document?

Answer (score 0):

Joe -

You can use jQuery to get the data from that URL and parse the XML.

> https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/
>
> https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

From there you need to determine whether you want to convert it into JSON or use it as is. There is not a simple and clean way to convert XML to JSON due to the attributes fields present, but here is an example of some code to do it:

> https://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json

If you are having cross domain issues, you will need to request that data server side with PHP, Java, Node.js or your back end of choice. You can do it with such things like this:

> JAVA  : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html
>
> PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php
>
> Node.js : https://davidwalsh.name/nodejs-http-request

Comment: Won't i run into the same issue? At least with a first attempt I did.

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: hmmm. still no luck.. pretty new to this and not sure it's possible using javascript

Comment: It doesn't look like there is any simple way to do this purely in javascript in the browser. You'll need to look into a server-side implementation to do this.